# mapsStatetoProps not called in Component inside another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import './App.css';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Sample } from './Sample';

export interface IAppProps {
  sap:any
}

class App extends React.Component<IAppProps> {
  constructor(props: IAppProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        {this.props.sap}
        <Sample />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export function mapStateToProps(state: any, ownProps: any) {
  return {
    sap:"THIS FROM APP"
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);


import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import './App.css';

export interface ISampleProps {
    newData?: any
}

export class Sample extends React.Component<ISampleProps> {
    constructor(props: ISampleProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render(): any {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                SAMPLe.....
                {this.props.newData}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export function mapStateToProps(state: any, ownProps: any) {
    return {
        newData: "Hello world"
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Sample);
```

output is missing "Hello world " after SAMPle...
[image]
Then there is a  component added in the render of the App component the mapStateToProps gets called for the App component but not the Sample component .

Why is the mapStateToProps not being called when used in the  component ?

The code example is to understand the concept of redux/react .

Comment: Your export for Sample class is not correct. With Brackets around the import is not the default export of Sample component so, `this.props.newData` is null. Remove the keyword `export` before your class and remove the brackets in your import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply fix your code by replacing

```
import { Sample } from './Sample';
```

with

```
import Sample  from './Sample';
```

when you use braces you're indicating that its one of the exports,
when you don't specify the braces its the default export you're referring to

the default export is the component which is connected to redux in your case